# Netlify deployment - Failed to fetch cache

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I don't normally have an issue deploying to Netlify. However, this time i'm getting a really short deploy log with a few issues not seen before. When i try to visit my site i get a blank page

```
LOG BELOW 

2:44:07 PM: Build ready to start

2:44:09 PM: build-image version: 9cade8af58c2cf3a17a1e9433d2e979149488837

2:44:09 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.5

2:44:09 PM: buildbot version: 2d05064ce3dd2eb95d282a24602ab707dd9581e8

2:44:09 PM: Fetching cached dependencies

2:44:09 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build

2:44:09 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build

2:44:10 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo

2:44:10 PM: git clone https://github.com/Jrowan19/PS-FRONTEND

2:44:10 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master

2:44:11 PM: No build command found, continuing to publishing

2:44:11 PM: Starting to deploy site from ‘/’

2:44:11 PM: Creating deploy tree

2:44:11 PM: 0 new files to upload

2:44:11 PM: 0 new functions to upload

2:44:11 PM: Starting post processing

2:44:11 PM: Post processing done

2:44:11 PM: Site is live

2:44:11 PM: Finished processing build request in 2.498321286s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the repository folder layout, the build directory should be `ps-frontend/build` not the root (`/`) folder.

[image]